# Avoid JavaScript Plugins Version Conflicts

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, conflict

I work in an environment that I don't always control what JavaScript files are included. On occasion I have another process that ads a diff JS version of a plugin I have already added. What happens? Boom, conflict.

I am curious if there is a way I can add some code to avoid this conflicts. I want the ability to have multiple versions of the same javascript plugin load, and gracefully allow the first one to take over.

Thoughts?

*** UPDATE ***

Allow me to clarify. I am using a PHP environment where "extensions" can be loaded. Each of the extensions can be from a different developer. These extensions provide different functions, but can often use the same libraries.

Let's take for example qTip: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

qTip hasn't been updated in quite some time. However, it's a great plugin. My code uses the most recenter version, someone else's code uses the older version. A code conflict ensues.

I want to alter their library to not load if qTip is already included, despite the version and avoid the conflict. The only other choice I'd have is to prefix the entire library name and run it as if it's another product, but that seems painful to me.

Thoughts?

Comment: To me it sounds like the php that controls the "extensions" needs to be updated to handle dependencies better.

Comment: WordPress isn't the best for this.  :P    I was hoping for a JS alternative.

Comment: I thought wordpress already handled this pretty well.. Maybe not as well as npm, but it has the tools available to have shared dependencies.

Comment: If this is about wordpress, consider adding the [wordpress] tag

Comment: I don't think js would help you with this, unless you completely moved away from the wordpress dependency system.

Comment: I was hoping for a JS solution, not a WordPress one. That's why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 1):

To have two different versions of the same plugin loaded would require two different versions of jQuery to be loaded too, since plugins always overwrite either `$.foo` or `$.fn.foo`.

This can be resolved along similar lines to jdphenix's answer using the `$.noConflict()` function.

```
<script src="jquery.js">      /* load first jquery instance */ </script>
<script src="plugin-v1.js">   /* attach to first instance */   </script>
<script> 
    var $j1 = $.noConflict(); /* remove $ and jQuery from globals */
</script>
<script src="jquery.js">      /* load second jquery instance */ </script>
<script src="plugin-v2.js">   /* attach to second instance */   </script>
<script>
    var $j2 = $.noConflict(); /* optionally remove $ and jQuery from globals again */
</script>
```

The later version of the plugin will be attached to `$` and `jQuery` (or `$j2` if you invoked `noConflict` again).  The earlier version will be accessible via `$j1`.

I expect that most jQuery functions would work regardless of which version was used to create the jQuery object, but testing is advised!

**EDIT** alternatively, on some (most?) plugins you might be able to get away with simply renaming the original handler before the next one is loaded.  This should be OK so long as the plugin doesn't try to invoke itself by name:

```
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script src="plugin-foo-v1.js"> </script>
<script>
    $.fn.bar = $.fn.foo;
    delete $.fn.bar;
</script>
<script src="plugin-foo-v2.js"> </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've tagged jquery so I assume this is the library in question. In the header:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    var $j2 = $.noConflict();
  </script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="sojs25190104.js" language="javascript"></script>
```

And sojs25190104.js:

```
(function () {
  console.log($.fn.jquery);
  console.log($j2.fn.jquery);
}());
```

What this accomplishes:

- jQuery 2.1.1 is available through the global `$j2`
- jQuery 1.11.1 is available through the global `$`

Comment: It's for a plugin that is jQuery based, but not jQuery itself.